# Product database - MySQL query with multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql

First, my table structure:

```
Products Table:

 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `list_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `brand` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Categories Table:

 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Brand Table:

 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `brand` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Stock Table:

 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `size` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sold` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `reserved` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `product_sizes` (`product_id`,`size`),
 KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `stock_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`)
```

I wanted a single SQL query that grabs all the products by whatever criteria, and adds the total stock and total sold from the `STOCK` table, the brand name from the `BRAND` table, the child and parent categories from the `CATEGORY` table.

This was my attempt, which doesn't work:

```
"SELECT
    a.title,
    COALESCE(SUM(e.stock),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(e.sold),0),
    a.price,
    c.category AS 'parent',
    d.category AS 'child',
    b.brand,
    a.featured
FROM
    products a
        JOIN brand b
            ON a.brand = b.id
        JOIN categories c
            ON a.category = c.id
        LEFT JOIN categories d
            ON c.parent = d.id
        JOIN stock e
            ON a.id = e.product_id

WHERE a.deleted = 0 ORDER BY a.title ASC"
```

Initially I had a series of queries instead - first getting all the products, then grabbing the categories, then the brands, then the stock/sold. I'm just wondering if I can do it all in the one query?

I am quite new at SQL.

Comment: How nested can the categories be?

Comment: What was the error with your attempt?

Comment: Why you said your attempt SQL statement didn't work? All side tables must have matches to the product table?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I am guessing that your query, as written, returns incorrect values.

Comment: @Shadow They can only be nested 2 levels deep (i.e. Men > Trousers)

it only returns one result, and the SUM seems to have added all stock for all items, rather than just the stock that matches that product ID.

Comment: @daninthemix Any aggregate function (such as sum()) will return 1 row in the absence of a group by clause.

Comment: @Shadow so can I not achieve what I'm trying here? Which is a resultset back with all the info for each product returned, including available stock and sold (each product will be in the stock table multiple times, once for each size of the product). I wanted to pass it all into a mysqli_fetch_assoc to then generate the page. My current method of doing that has multiple SQL queries for each product.

Comment: You can achieve it, but you have to do a group by on all fields in the select list but the two with the sum(). In mysql you might be able to get away by doing a group by on product.id under certain settings, but I would not recommend you to do that.

Comment: @Shadow ok, GROUP BY a.id seems to work. Thanks! Couple more things - am I able to also return a.id as a column? It seemed to break when I tried that. Do I lose the ability to use ORDER BY if I'm already using GROUP BY (i.e. can I no longer alphabetize the results?). Lastly, what would your suggestion - doing 'GROUP BY' on everything - look like? I tried to write it in but it made a mess and threw errors.

Thanks v.much for your help.

Comment: @Shadow oops just syntax errors. All sorted now. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Shadow, this is the query I needed, which works great:

```
    SELECT
    a.id,
    a.title,
    COALESCE(SUM(e.stock),0) AS 'stock',
    COALESCE(SUM(e.sold),0) AS 'sold',
    a.price,
    c.category AS 'child_category',
    d.category AS 'parent_category',
    b.brand,
    a.featured
FROM
    products a
        JOIN brand b
            ON a.brand = b.id
        JOIN categories c
            ON a.category = c.id
        LEFT JOIN categories d
            ON c.parent = d.id
        JOIN stock e
            ON a.id = e.product_id

WHERE a.deleted = 0
GROUP BY a.id, a.title, a.price, c.category, d.category, b.brand, a.featured ORDER BY a.title ASC
```

Comment: This is exactly the approach I wrote I would not recommend. It is against the sql standard and runs in mysql under certain settings only.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your suggestion though. Were you saying I should put GROUP BY and then list every single field in the select, minus the two SUM items?

Comment: Yep, `group by a.id, a.title, a.price,...`

Comment: @Shadow great, thankyou again. I've amended the answer.